# Running sum with aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am retrieving the results of the `mlog` table and calculate the subtotal of the `qtyn` with the help of following code 1. I am stuck with how to join my second code criteria with the first.

Thanks for any help

1.

```
SELECT autn, date, itcode, qtyn, out,
       date, phstock,
       qtyn + COALESCE(
                (SELECT SUM(qtyn) FROM  dbo.mlog b
                 WHERE b.autn < a.autn
                     AND itcode = '40'), 0) AS balance
FROM dbo.mlog a
WHERE (itcode = '40')
ORDER BY autn
```

2.

```
date >=(SELECT MAX([date]) FROM mlog)
```

Comment: @MartinSmith maybe `SQL Server` because of the bracket used around `date` column. *I guess*.

Comment: @marc_s Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1399.06

Comment: As your second code snippet is a condition I am afraid I do not fully understand where and how you want the code to be joined? To what 'date' are you referring on the left side of the clause?

Comment: the date is a simply a column both code 1 and 2. And join I mean only to link with the first code. In other words put the second code in 'WHERE' part in first code

Comment: I have added a sample of how to join, if you need an `or` simply replace the `AND` with `OR`. But like @alzaimar I do not understand the second piece of code `date >= (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM mlog)`. You will only get results where date is the maximum date in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append a condition to the code, use `AND` or `OR`. EG:

```
SELECT a.autn, a.date, a.itcode, a.qtyn, a.out,
       a.date, a.phstock,
       a.qtyn + COALESCE(
                (SELECT SUM(b.qtyn) FROM  dbo.mlog b
                 WHERE b.autn < a.autn
                     AND b.itcode = '40'), 0) AS balance
FROM dbo.mlog a
WHERE (a.itcode = '40' AND a.date >= (SELECT MAX([c.date]) FROM mlog c) )
ORDER BY a.autn
```

*Not tested, but should do what you want*

Comment: It will definitely help to add explicit alias prefixes on all conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that SQL Server is rather inefficient with `coalesce()`, because it runs the first part twice.  Here is an alternative way of writing this:

```
with ml as (
    SELECT ml.autn, ml.date, ml.itcode, ml.qtyn, ml.out, ml.date, ml.phstock
    FROM dbo.mlog ml
    WHERE ml.itcode = '40' AND ml.date >= (SELECT MAX(ml1.date]) FROM mlog ml1)
   )
select ml.*,
       (select sum(m1l.qtyn) from ml ml1 where ml1.autn <= ml.autn) as balance
from ml
ORDER BY ml.autn
```

I also wonder if the `where` clause would be more efficient as:

```
    WHERE ml.itcode = '40' AND ml.date = (SELECT top 1 ml1.date FROM mlog ml1 order by ml1.date desc)
```

Comment: `COALESCE` gets turned into a `CASE` statement and is ANSI standard. `ISNULL` is not standard. Also, the order of precedence takes effect with `COALESCE`. To read more: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30013/2334